# How do you do mobile navigation (forward & back transition) with UI-Router and Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to emulate the typical progression from screen to screen on mobile devices with a "nextTransition" for forward navigation and a "backTransition" when he user go back. I know how to do it in Angular 1.2X but now with the Angular 1.3X and the new UI-Router I don't know what's the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be sure to use `$state.go()` to navigate from within controllers. In templates, there is a directive `ui-sref` which you can point at a state by name (e.g. `ui-sref="tab.home"`) You can learn more about navigation in ui-router here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#activating-a-state

The best thing about ui-router is that you can declare nested states and views which inherit data and ui-views from parents. In [my code](https://github.com/gardner/embassynetwork/blob/c664e039fbb36e79c52608e34c09c9171a3b74d2/app/scripts/app.js#L54) the `$stateProvider` is injected into my app's `module().config()` block where the state is defined all in one place.

Using nested states allows you a more three dimensional work flow. The most important thing to grok is that child states will load their templates into their parent's ui-view. Please take a few minutes to read https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#nested-states--views

Additionally, if you are just getting started setting up a web app then please search for "yeoman angular generator". Yeoman has saved me loads of time by generating a basic framework for different types of apps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer do you have a simple implementation of navigation back and forth from screen to screen ? like a plunkr ? I am aware of the "nesting" and the "activating" of states but I don't see how to use them to apply the right transition...